# Windows Volume Icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, volume-mixer

Just a quick query on the windows volume control icon which is displayed at the upper left corner of screen when you change the volume. When I have fullscreen programs open like games, this icon does not show. How do I adjust the settings such that this is displayed above everything?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most games have borderless window mode next to fullscreen & window. It should look exactly like fullscreen with these desktop features enabled.

Note that this may decrease performance & features like nVidia Shadowplay may become unavailable.

Comment: Ohhh very interesting thanks for this. So i'm guessing there is no easy way to enable desktop features on top of full screen?

Comment: Well when you run in fullscreen, desktop does not render, so it would have to "inject" Dx or OpenGL like rivatuner does to display the overlay.